# How do I determine the object to form a relative clause when joining two sentences?

Tags: relative-clauses

The building over there is owned by a large corporation. I have forgotten the name of the building.

There are three newcomers in our class.All of them speak Spanish.

In both of these sentences, when I join the sentences with relative pronouns, how do I determine what is the object I am making the clause refer to? Is it 'the building over there' or 'the building'? ‘three newcomers in our class' or 'three newcomers'? How do I accurately determine them? As it affects whether I use a defining or non-defining relative clause to join the sentence.

Comment: "The building over there, whose name I've forgotten, is owned by a large corporation" ("whose" has "building over there" as antecedent).  /  "There are three newcomers in our class, all of whom speak Spanish" ("whom" has the nominal "newcomers" as antecedent).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1: *I have <strike>forgot</strike> forgotten the name of the building over there, **[comma] which** is owned by a large corporation.*

> 2: *There are three newcomers in our class, **all of whom** speak Spanish.*

Example #2 is one of those relatively uncommon contexts where most native speakers would continue to use ***whom*** (which is increasingly being replaced by ***who*** in other contexts). But then again, most native speakers probably wouldn't say #2 anyway - they'd more likely just say...

> 2a: *The three newcomers in our class all speak Spanish.*

---

Note the comma in my example #1. Without that, the text after ***...over there*** would be a ***defining*** clause (singling out ***that particular*** building because it's the which is owned by a large corporation; by implication the others *aren't).

Comment: But what if the relative clause in sentence 1 was used as a defining relative clause behind 'the building'?

Comment: The building over there, the name of which I have forgotten, is owned by a large corporation.

Comment: Would "The building whose name I've forgotten over there is owned by a large corporation" mean the same?

Comment: That last example in your comment *would* mean the same as my example #1, but native speakers wouldn't be likely to say it anyway., because it's better to keep short preposition-based adverbial elements like *[over] **there*** closer to the relevant noun (***the building***, in this case). Longer, more complex elements (with their own "internal" subject+verb components), such as ***whose name I have forgotten,*** can be placed further away if necessary.